# Microsoft Visual C++ doesn't respond when building a project

Tags: visual-c++, building

When I Build, VC++ 6 will show "Linking..." and the programs NEVER get linked. I tried pressing STOP but no use. I cant even close VC++ as it says its still bulding a project.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the project's properties, under the Linker tab, set the /VERBOSE flag and it might help you see what it's loading, and where it's choking.  Be prepared to kill the task (having Task Manager in the foreground before starting would be smart.)  Also, be prepared because the /VERBOSE flag can cause a lot! of output.  But your answer is likely in there somewhere.

Other things to check:  you may have a lock on the output file.  If you're trying to link an executable that's part of a program that you are already running, it might hang on you (although I think it's more likely to give you some kind of "can't delete" error.)

Answer (score 0):

In task manager, end task "cl.exe" and/or "link.exe".